# How Can I find any Object when I know property value of object

Tags: javascript, object, methods, clone, shortcut

I try create shortcut to icon (html element), which is object and this object has some methods for example. openWindow(), and I want that, when I will click on shortcut,this shortcut run method this object (orginal html element).

Example:

```js
class File{
  constructor(fileName){
  this.name = fileName;
  this.element = document.createElement("div");
  this.addFile();
  }
  
  openWindow(){
    console.log("You opened", this.name);
  }
  
  addFile(){
    document.body.appendChild(this.element);
    this.element.addEventListener('click',openWindow)
  }
}

const orginalElement = new File("file1");

const shortcut = orginalElement.cloneNode(true);
shortcut.addEventListener('click', openWindow);
```

Maybe I should use WeakMap or something other I don't know.
So Is any method, which can return object when I know property value of object?
Because in my code each object has 'id' property and thoose shortcuts has attribute 'id' which should be same as property id of orginal object.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can use arrow functions within your class to [make them automatically bound to `this`, no matter how you use them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#arrow_functions_used_as_methods).

```js
class FileIcon {
  constructor(fileName) {
    this.name = fileName;
    this.addFile();
  }

  openWindow = () => {
    console.log("You opened", this.name);
  }

  addFile() {
    this.element = document.createElement("button");
    this.element.innerText = "Button " + this.name;
    document.body.appendChild(this.element);
    this.element.addEventListener('click', this.openWindow);
  }
}

const a = new FileIcon("foo");
const b = new FileIcon("bar");

const link = document.createElement("a");
link.href = "#";
link.innerText = "Link for foo";
link.addEventListener("click", a.openWindow);
document.body.appendChild(link);
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know, that as second argument, can type object with method.